# Handaling information from a dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I'll try to keep it as brief as possible. I've been struggling with this few days now.

The goal of my code is to echo out a list of names, each name have a role assigned:

```
switch ($row["c_type"]) {
                case "0": $ind0++; $artists0 .= "$case0";
```

and

```
$case0= "<div> 

    <strong>
               <a href='/names/advanced_search?" . $querystringparams . urlencode($row["position"]) .  "&pg=1'>" . lng($row["role"],null,true). "</a>
 </strong>
                                - <a href='/names/" . $row["id"]. "/" . encodeURL($row["name"]) . "'>
<span itemprop='name'>". $row["name"] . "". $row["name"] . "</span></a></div>";
```

so far so good the code prints the lines of the array like :

**IT** - John Smith

**Director** - Smith Jones

**IT** - Jane

But my goal is to make it look like :

**IT** - John Smith, Jane

**Director** - Smith Jones

Usually I would make it if `$row[position]==$row[position] $case0=`... 
But in this case both the values are elements of the same array and the code just goes trough the rows in the db and prints them.

I would appreciate any advice you may have.

Comment: You need to store your data in an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create array with as key the position and as values the people. Then loop over that array and echo the contents.

```
<?php
$organisation = array(); // better name welcome
while ($row = ...)
{
    $organisation[$row['position']][] = $row['name'];
}

foreach ($organisation as $position => $employees)
{
    echo '<strong>' . $position . '</strong>';
    echo implode(', ', $employees);
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

**Edit**

I can imagine the `$organisation[$row['position']][]` part looks confusing. $row['position'] returns the position like 'IT'. It would then become $organisation['IT'][], which means you add a value to the array named $organisation['IT']. So $organisation is actually an array of arrays.